# Ninja operation is not permitted on Android studio

Tags: android, cmake, ninja

I was working with CMAKE and I faced this error about ninja build which says the operation is not permitted. I've spend around 3 days for this problem and I finally fixed that with weird solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
1)remove android studio and install again.
2)remove your repos and fetch repos again.
3)enjoy